# Loading dylib in python fails on macOS Big Sur: `Symbol not found: ___addtf3`

Tags: python, c++, gcc, dylib, macos-big-sur

I have trouble when loading a custom `mylib.dylib` in python3.7 on Mac OS X Big Sur 11.1:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-21ad9f6d803b> in <module>
     12 try:
---> 13     mylib = ctypes.CDLL(mylib_path)
     14 except OSError:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:

OSError: dlopen(mylib.dylib, 6): Symbol not found: ___addtf3
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libquadmath.0.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libquadmath.0.dylib
```

**However** exactly the same `mylib.dylib` is loading successfully with exactly this python code on Mac OS X 10.15 Catalina. **Moreover**, exactly the same `mylib` binary runs successfully on my Big Sur 11.1 when compiled as an executable, not as a shared library.

Detailed step-by-step description:

1. I build a C++ code in a shared library using `bazel` on Mac OS X Big Sur 11.1:

```
bazel build :mylib.dylib
```

`BUILD` file is:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "mylib.dylib",
    srcs = ["mylib.cc", "mylib.h", "mylib_external.cc", "mylib_external.h"],
    deps = [
        ...some dependencies...
    ],
    linkshared = 1,
)
```

`.bazelrc` file is:

```
# Basic build settings
build --jobs 128
build --define='absl=1'
build --enable_platform_specific_config

# macOS
build:macos --cxxopt=-std=c++17
build:macos --host_cxxopt=-std=c++17
build:macos --copt=-w

# Sets the default Apple platform to macOS.
build --apple_platform_type=macos

# Allow debugging with XCODE
build --apple_generate_dsym

build:darwin_x86_64 --apple_platform_type=macos
build:darwin_x86_64 --macos_minimum_os=10.12
build:darwin_x86_64 --cpu=darwin_x86_64
```

2. Then I try to load it in python3.7:

```
import sys, platform
import ctypes, ctypes.util

mylib_path = ctypes.util.find_library("mylib")
if not mylib_path:
    print("Unable to find the specified library.")
    sys.exit()

try:
    mylib = ctypes.CDLL(mylib_path)
except OSError:
    print("Unable to load the specified library.")
    sys.exit()
```

And it gives me:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-21ad9f6d803b> in <module>
     12 try:
---> 13     mylib = ctypes.CDLL(mylib_path)
     14 except OSError:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:

OSError: dlopen(mylib.dylib, 6): Symbol not found: ___addtf3
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libquadmath.0.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libquadmath.0.dylib
```

A possible solution to the same problem was discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/citwild/laugh-finder/issues/11), but for me, changing `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` does not work.

3. I tried to set the path to `libgcc_ext.10.4.dylib` in `libquadmath.0.dylib`:

```
install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libgcc_ext.10.4.dylib /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libquadmath.0.dylib
```

It might help because there is no `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` on Big Sur 11.1 (so this file is not used I suppose), but instead it gives me a new error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-21ad9f6d803b> in <module>
     12 try:
---> 13     mylib = ctypes.CDLL(mylib_path)
     14 except OSError:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:

OSError: dlopen(mylib.dylib, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libgcc_ext.10.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libquadmath.0.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libgcc_ext.10.4.dylib: mach-o, but wrong filetype
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/lib/gcc/10/libgcc_ext.10.4.dylib: mach-o, but wrong filetype
```

4. I also [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65332141/cant-compile-c-on-os-x-big-sur-ld-library-not-found-for-lgcc-s-10-4) to `brew reinstall gcc`, before this action there was `/usr/local/libSystem.B.dylib` instead of `flat namespace` in the actual issue.
5. There are some related issues: [scipy](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1467), [scipy.special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667876/failed-scipy-special-import-symbol-not-found-addtf3), [scipy._fblas](https://github.com/yosinski/deep-visualization-toolbox/issues/104), [gdal2](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/issues/301). Their solutions do not help, because usually, they are about re-installing the packages, and here I have my own package.
6. Eventually, I tried to set `CC=clang/g++/g++-10` when [building with bazel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356173/how-to-use-clang-instead-g-in-bazel). Unfortunately, it did not work.

Any suggestions and thoughts would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: ___addtf3 is a gcc runtime function, usually defined in libgcc_s shared library. Does your custom dylib reference this library?

Comment: Thank you! Your advice led to a solution, will describe it in detail in "Answers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @n. 'pronouns' m. advice from the comments, I tried to link libgcc_s instead of libSystem:

```
install_name_tool -change "/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib" "/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libgcc_s.1.dylib" mylib.dylib
```

It gave me another error: `Symbol not found: ___emutls_get_address` from libopenblas. I googled and found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414786/missing-emutls-get-address-with-gcc-4-7-and-openmp), and did:

```
brew link --overwrite gcc
```

Then the only thing I did is rebuilt the `mylib.dylib` with bazel with exact the same rules as earlier and it worked! Now the library loads in python without any errors. Thank you so much.